# Manage multiple navigators (stack navigator and bottomtabsnavigator) in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a react native application which has got a stack navigator and a bottom tabs navigator. Bottom tabs navigator and stack navigator has common screens between them. Here is the structure:

```
const ExploreNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Explore: {
        screen: ExploreScreen
    },
    Read: {
        screen: ReadScreen
    },
    CreateImage: {
        screen: CreateImageScreen
    }
})




const TabsNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    ExploreTab: {
        screen: ExploreNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Explore"
        }
    },
    ReadTab: {
        screen: ReadScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Read"
        }
    }
})
```

**Now, if I directly move to Reading screen from Bottom tab navigator and move to CreateImage screen of stack navigator, when I press the back button I come back to default screen that is explore screen?**

So, what is the best approach to solve the issue? I know I can create another stack navigator and add the relevant screens. Also, if this approach is followed can I name the stack navigator screens same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this doesn't need keed one screen in the bold stack and bottom tab. So I suggestion like this

```
const ExploreNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Tabs: {
        screen: TabsNavigator
    },
    CreateImage: {
        screen: CreateImageScreen
    }
})




const TabsNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Explore: {
        screen: ExploreScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Explore"
        }
    },
    ReadTab: {
        screen: ReadScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Read"
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this

```js
    const ExploreNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ExplorePrimary: {
        screen: ExploreScreen
    },
    ReadPrimary: {
        screen: ReadScreen
    },
    CreateImagePrimary: {
        screen: CreateImageScreen
    }
  })

  const ReadNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ExplorePrimary: {
        screen: ExploreScreen
    },
    ReadSecond: {
        screen: ReadScreen
    },
    CreateImageSecond: {
        screen: CreateImageScreen
    }
  })




  const TabsNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    ExploreTab: {
        screen: ExploreNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Explore"
        }
    },
    ReadTab: {
        screen: ReadNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: "Read"
        }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Hi, suppose if I want to move from ReadScreen to CreateImageScreen, I have two different routeNames depending on from where I navigated from. so, how can I resolve that issue?

Comment: if you are on ReadTab: navigation.navigate('CreateImageSecond')
if on explore: navigation.navigate('CreateImagePrimary')

Comment: my approach is good if you want to persist the bottom tabs on create image screen

Comment: Hi, so in my usecase there are 2 scenarios:
1. Move from explore screen to read screen to CreateImageScreen.
2. Directly move from read screen to createImageScreen.

So, in your case how can I know from where do I land up in ReadScreen and then update the navigator accordingly?