# React navigation createBottomTabNavigator v4 to v6 with multiple screens in each tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

My question relates to migrating / upgrading some code from React Navigation v4 to v6.

I have an existing application using React Navigation v4.  It utilizes a bottom tab navigator (createBottomTabNavigator) with code that broadly does this:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  { 
    MapStack: createStack(
      
    ), 
    NotificationsStack:createStack(

    ), 
    SettingsStack: createStack(

    ) 
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBar
  }
);
```

In this example, I have three options from the bottom tab navigator for a map, notifications and settings.   Different screens can be accessed in each case. This essentially means there is a stack navigator embedded within the tab navigator. The `createStack` is defined as follows:

```
const createStack = (label, Icon, ...rest) => {
}
```

This returns the (1) screens to access from each option in the bottom tab navigator, (2) the path and (3) navigation labels and icons for the tab bar.

I can see there are some examples, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64182225/manage-multiple-navigators-stack-navigator-and-bottomtabsnavigator-in-react-na) which give some ideas on how to do this in React Navigation v6.  However, I'm after a better example which indicates how to include a stack navigator inside a tab navigator with **multiple screens** in each case.  The example above has a single screen.